# One specific parameter value causes no other values to be returned

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm running into the strangest issue in SSRS 2008 R2. I'm building a report with several parameters. One parameter, Funding Source, accepts multiple values. For the most part it works as expected and returns any matching rows. The exception is when one specific parameter value is included, but ONLY if it is also the first value in the list. In this specific case I only see rows that match this value. The value is "CBCHB (CDC) - Littoral - PY4 - Apr18-Mar19".

If that value is excluded, or if something else is first in the selected list, then I see all rows as expected. The tablix is populated by stored procedure, and if I try to replicate these conditions directly in the sp then I see the expected results (e.g. all matches appear) so I assume there's something wrong with my report file.

The only other thing I can think of that might be related (or might not be) is that the list of Funding Source values available is set conditionally based on the results of previous parameters. The offending value is the first in the default list, so this bug pops up initially every time I run the report. If I output the selected parameter values directly into the body of my report then I see everything expected, not just the offending value.

Has anyone encountered something like this or have suggestions on how to troubleshoot further? I'm flummoxed. I'm happy to provide any code samples on request but couldn't immediately think of what would be relevant or helpful.

Comment: How are the parameters being passed to the stored procedure? e.g. if the SP accepts a varchar(50) then that one value will fill it up, that might be your problem

Comment: Also, is "CBCHB (CDC) - Littoral - PY4 - Apr18-Mar19" the Label or the Value?

Comment: Also, within the stored procedure, how are the multi-select items split out, presumably you have some sort of StringSplit udf that returns a table for an IN condition?

Comment: "... and if I try to replicate these conditions directly in the sp then I see the expected results (e.g. all matches appear) ..." - would be useful to see the code for that. Sorry for all the comments, I'm just running through different possibilities. My initial thought is, if SSRS shows you a list of chosen parameter items, thats what it will be sending to the SP, so the problem is more likely within the SP

Comment: "If I output the selected parameter values directly into the body of my report then I see everything expected, not just the offending value." - ok this makes me think the problem is definitely within your SP somewhere, perhaps at the point where the comma-separated item list is split out

Comment: @codeulike thanks for these possibilities! Your point about vs value got me thinking - I was using it as both, which is probably not great practice. I switched out the value to an actual numeric identifier and, while I still don't understand the problem, that resolved it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the funding source names as both label and value. I switched out the value to an actual numeric identifier and left the label as it was, and that resolved it. (I think this is the proper way to close a self-solved question?)